# How to prevent replacement by subsequent s/// (empty pattern for replacement) in sed?

Tags: sed

```
a=a
b=ab
c=''
d=''
echo ac | sed "s/$a/$b/;"
abc
echo ac | sed "s/$a/$b/; s/$c/$d/"
bc
```

sed removes the character 'a' in the last example, because when sed is passed the subsequent s command with an empty pattern, the previous one is used, in this case, $a instead empty $c, which is 'a'.

[The POSIX specification for sed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sed.html)

> If an RE is empty (that is, no pattern is specified) sed shall behave
> as if the last RE used in the last command applied (either as an
> address or as part of a substitute command) was specified.

In a real script, variables $c $d can be either empty or defined. For defined variables $c $d a subsequent s command must be executed, but how to prevent replacement by a subsequent s command for the case of empty variables in sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do it if the variable is empty:

```
sed "s/$a/$b/; ${c:+s/$c/$d/}"
```

`${parameter:+word}` is one of [variable expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) - if `var` is null or unset, if expands to nothing, otherwise the expansion of `word` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, `sed` has no sensible way of making the second substitution conditional on the emptiness of `$c`. `sed` isn't designed for that kind of thing.

However, you could bodge up something which does what you want. For example, you could use a 'noop' operation to reset the default regular expression to something very unlikely:

```
$ echo ac | sed "s/$a/$b/; /^x\{80\}$/h; s/$c/$d/"
abc
```

This is a proper bodge though. For one thing, sed doesn't have a real noop - I've abused `h` in this example. And for another thing, you always run the risk of 'very unlikely' actually happening.

You'd be better off checking `$c` in a shell wrapper and, if it is empty, invoking `sed` with only the first substitution.

Comment: as I understand, the pattern /^x\{80\}$/ mean 'xxx....xxx' ('x' is repeated 80 times). But what does the command /^x\{80\}$/h do exactly?

Comment: So /^x\{80\}$/h copies any line matching 80 lots of 'x' to the hold space. But in this case I'm abusing `h` as a noop, so an operation that does nothing. The point of that command is solely to reset the default regular expression to one which is very unlikely to match any input, so that the following `s///` won't do anything

Comment: without abuse h, jast a very unlikely substitution before, is this variant a bad choise?  $ a=a; b=ba;  echo aa| sed "s/$a/$b/; s/^x\{80\}$/$d/; s/$c/$d/;"
baa